# C++ can't access private variables in class

Tags: c++, class

I have `Vector.h`:

```
class Vector
{
private:
    int* _elements;
    int _capacity; // Total places can be used
    int _size; // Size of current taken places
    int _resizeFactor; // how many cells to add when need to reallocate
}
```

And `Vector.cpp`:

```
// Constructor
Vector::Vector(int n = 10) {
    if (n < 2) {
        n = 2;
    }

    this->_elements = new int[n];
    this->_capacity = n;
    this->_size = 0;
    this->_resizeFactor = n;

}

// Return the size of the vector
int Vector::size() const {
    this->_size = 0; // I have an error here

    // calculate size
    for (int i = 0; i < _capacity; i++) {
        if (this->_elements[i] != 0) {
            this->_size++; // I have an error here too
        }
    }

    return this->_size; // and here
}
```

I initialize the variable `_size` in the constructor and it worked fine.
But when I'm trying to increase it (`this->_size++`) or return it, I get `expression must be a modifiable lvalue` error

Why? how to deal with it?

Comment: Why do you modify the size in a function that should only return it? Also, how would your vector be able to store the value `0`? You have a flaw in your design.

Comment: As for your error, you state that the `size()` function is `const`. That means it can't modify member variables.

Comment: And *please* create a proper [mre] to show us.

Comment: Note that every one of those `this->`s can be removed without affecting the meaning of the code. They're just noise.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is declared `const`. This is a promise that you will not modify the object while the method is executing. Your broke that promise hence the compiler error.

Here are three things you can do (in reverse order of how good they are, my opinion of course)

1. Remove the `const`
2. Declare `_size` as mutable

   ```
   mutable int _size; // Size of current taken places
   ```

mutable members are exceptions to the normal const rules.

3. Remove `_size` from your class, the fact that you are getting into trouble with `_size` is a big hint that it's should not be in the class at all. Instead make `_size` a local variable in your `size` method

   ```
    // Return the size of the vector
    int Vector::size() const {
        int size = 0;
        // calculate size
        for (int i = 0; i < _capacity; i++) {
            if (this->_elements[i] != 0)
                size++;
        }
        return size;
    }
   ```

Unrelated to the question, but the fact that you consider zero elements to be not part of your vector is a bit weird.